# What is the most optimal way of getting the Instant time in C#?

Tags: c#, nodatime

I'm working on a codebase where they use two different approaches for getting the Instant time from [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) using C#.

The first approach is from using an object with [IClock](https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/api/NodaTime.IClock.html)

```
IClock.GetCurrentInstant()
```

The second approach is from using [Instant.FromDateTimeUtc](https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/api/NodaTime.Instant.html#NodaTime_Instant_FromDateTimeUtc_System_DateTime_) and [DateTime.UtcNow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.utcnow?view=netframework-4.8).

```
Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.UtcNow)
```

Which one is best practice?

Comment: Is there any reason as to why they would have two different approaches in their codebase?

Comment: The answer I got for now is that one I asked didn't know why and it could just be two different preferences. It could be something more, I'm trying to find out if there is any good reason for it.

Comment: The biggest difference is that `Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.UtcNow)` will always get the date from the *real* system clock, while `IClock.GetCurrentInstant()` will get it from whatever clock is stored in the `IClock`, which could be a unit testable clock or a clock that is mocked in some other way.

Comment: I think `IClock` is the best practice in ***this*** senario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the [NodaTime API reference](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/api/NodaTime.IClock.html):

> IClock is intended for use anywhere you need to have access to the current time.

The `Instant.FromDateTimeUtc` method looks to be intended as a way to get existing `DateTime` structures into the `Instant` format, rather than the proper way to get the current time. So, according to the API reference, you should use the `IClock` method for the purpose you mentioned above.